# where can i get the GCC binary?

Tags: gcc

I want to get the latest GCC linux binary, a simple link->download. Does anyone know of any such place? I'm having a hard time finding one.

Of course there is the possibility of downloading the source code and compiling it - but the instructions in 
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html
are both long and gruesome so it would have been nice to simply get the binary, if i can.

EDIT: i am not an administrator on my computer, so i can't use apt-get install.

Comment: A bit cruel guys. First of all - I'm not the guy that decides what gets into STO - but it seems to me this is the best place to ask general questions which programmers encounter - and as such its a shame to be so strict on which questions can be asked. I mean the end goal is programmers helping other programmers, so why that square. Regarding research effort - I actually did invest more than an hour searching, and so far - no luck ( yes i got to the page listing the sites with the binaries - but most of the links aren't for linux, and in the ones that are i wasn't able to find the binary in).

Comment: Again, I realize that my difficulties arise from being a GCC + Linux newb - but after searching for a similar question in STO and not finding one - i assumed it would be in place to ask here, if only for a clear simple answer that would also help other newbs.

Comment: You could download the .deb and extract it to a directory you own.

Comment: @Billy This was what I ended up doing. But it is annoying. GCC & G++ together depended on 34 packages, 34 separate .deb files I had to download, checksum, and extract. I also had to supply LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the compiler could find its library files. It does work, but I'm surprised there's no easier way to run a portable compiler not tied into the OS.

Comment: @Boann Yeah, that can be difficult. If you're still interested, look into GCC toolchains. Most of the time they are used to distribute cross compilers but some might exist for native builds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it on Windows, [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a good way to do it.

Comment: sorry - i meant linux, editted it in.

Answer (score 1):

From the package repository for whatever distribution you are using. GCC isn't the most portable of binaries.

Comment: sorry, wasn't clear before. I don't have sudo privilege on my computer, so i need to get by hand the binary file.

Comment: So you want a binary that will run from an arbitrary place in your home directory? Build it from source.

Comment: If only it were that easy - the instruction pdf in http://www.gnuarm.com/pdf/gccinstall.pdf is 37 (generally unreadable) pages long.

Comment: … or ask a system admin to install it for you. GCC is a very complex piece of software with lots of dependencies, getting it running from a home directory is not for the faint hearted.

Comment: ... sys admin are useless where i am

Comment: and again, i don't get the offensive attitude. Just a guy with a question asking in a place where guys ask questions.